# Can Darien Drinkwater be considered evil?

Tags: larry-gonick, kokopelli-attack-of-the-smart-pies

<sub>There will be many unmarked spoilers for *Kokopelli & Co. In Attack of the Smart Pies* by Larry Gonick here. Just a warning.</sub>

---

Darien Drinkwater is, indisputably, the main antagonist of *Attack of the Smart Pies*. He

- kills Emma's parents
- steals Emma's number and key
- kidnaps Mrs. Krishnamurti
- attempts to poison Mrs. Krishnamurti

And does some other stuff that may not be so nice.

But, we can explain why he did these things - the car crash that killed Emma's parents was an accident. He explained that he couldn't turn himself in because of his wife, who got a head injury and doesn't remember what happened. He then takes in Emma as a foster child, even though he never wanted a child around, in an attempt to make things right. He doesn't even get angry when she burns his posterior half off.

He takes the key and number, and tries to take the money, because he feels he deserves it - he did take care of Emma for many years. My theory here is that he has slightly unhinged by the death of his wife, if you feel like that's a stronger argument.

He accidentally knocks Mrs. Krishnamurti's head on the concrete, and takes her and locks her in the basement - she will interfere with her worries about Emma not being at school (she's the teacher). Drinkwater even gives her a whole lot of sandwiches (okay, they were meat and she's a vegetarian, but he gave her food), and even the newspapers that she asks for.

He only tries to poison her because Feather suggested it (this is complicated and requires knowledge of the book), it didn't sound like he was planning on killing her (although I could be missing it).

And he says that he never meant for anything to happen like that, that he didn't mean to hurt anyone (around p. 88 IIRC). He does attempt to hurt Koko at the end, though...

Through all of this, we also have to consider that he had just lost his wife, and that he was very good to Emma before all of this. He does exhibit some alarming qualities before this, though, like screaming at his wife with his eyes closed while driving the car.

**Can we consider Darien Drinkwater to be objectively evil**?